# App crashes on Android 6.0 launch, Logcat included, new developer

Tags: java, android, performance, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow

So I have very little experience with Java but I can learn it quickly. When launching the app in Marshmallow 6.0 . It suddenly crashes. I can get this from logcat in the Android Studio

**SKIP THE STRIKED TEXT AS ITS BEEN CORRECTED**

<s>E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime: Process: nezibo.com.dreamception, PID: 1863
    E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nezibo.com.dreamception/nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    E/AndroidRuntime:         at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    E/AndroidRuntime:         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at nezibo.com.dreamception.utils.FileUtils.removeTMPFiles(FileUtils.java:31)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:186)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)</s>

**CRASHLYTICS SHOWS THIS**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nezibo.com.dreamception/nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
   at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
   at nezibo.com.dreamception.utils.FileUtils.removeTMPFiles(FileUtils.java)
   at nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java)
   at nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

**FileUtils.java**

```
package nezibo.com.dreamception.utils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import nezibo.com.dreamception.Dreamception;
import nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.FilterActivity;

import static     android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult;
public class FileUtils {

public static void removeTMPFiles(Context context){
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    File dir = new File(Dreamception.GALLERY_LOCATION);
    for(File file : dir.listFiles()){
        if(file.getName().contains(FilterActivity.TEMP_FILE_MARKER)){
            paths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    String[] mStringArray = new String[paths.size()];
    mStringArray = paths.toArray(mStringArray);
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, mStringArray, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        /*
         */
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**LINE 31 from sniplet above**

```
for(File file : dir.listFiles()){
```

**Edit, So now This is what happens now I fixed the crash at launch, its becoming clear I need to change how permissions are being assigned for the new android.**

```
11-03 04:43:43.541 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/libcrashlytics: Failed to find any usable unwinding libraries on the device, falling back to simple unwinding
11-03 04:43:43.676 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ACRA: ACRA#init called but no ReportsCrashes annotation on Application nezibo.com.dreamception
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime: Process: nezibo.com.dreamception, PID: 9552
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:142)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=9552, uid=10059 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:29)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:296)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:54)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:42)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:128)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
11-03 04:45:07.230 9552-10585/nezibo.com.dreamception E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
11-03 04:45:07.400 9552-9693/nezibo.com.dreamception E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1376b20
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread: Activity nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity$6@b5b5ae2 that was originally bound here
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread: android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity$6@b5b5ae2 that was originally bound here
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1092)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity.initBilling(MainActivity.java:274)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at nezibo.com.dreamception.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-03 04:45:07.463 9552-9552/nezibo.com.dreamception E/ActivityThread:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-03 04:45:08.554 9552-9693/nezibo.com.dreamception E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1377ae0
```

**Manifest permission request.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- Allows access to the flashlight -->
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `NullPointerException` in your code. Post your code for `FileUtils.removeTMPFiles()` method here so we can suggest anything.

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
  at nezibo.com.dreamception.utils.FileUtils.removeTMPFiles(FileUtils.java)
```

Changes suggested:

```
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    File dir = new File(Dreamception.GALLERY_LOCATIONc);
    for(File file : dir.listFiles()){
```

to

```
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    File dir = new File(Dreamception.GALLERY_LOCATION);
    if(!dir.exists())return;
    for(File file : dir.listFiles()){
```

+++New code for change/request in permission

```
if(!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) { 
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2909); 
} else { 
    // continue with your code 
}
```

Comment: I posted it in body with line 31 below, thanks for the quick reply this is huge after the day i had

Comment: Well, this bug only affects 6.0 and permissions handling is changed, would it be possible its not getting permissions correctly?

EDIT, Ok cool ill try it out

Comment: WOW, That fixed it! I still need to do a lot more testing, you are the man. Do u have somewhere I can donate a few $

EDIT.. Nevermind now it launched but still crashed when you try and use it, ill post some more details

Comment: In 6.0 they have added new permission mechanism known as Dynamic Permission. For that We have to add support for 6.0 in your app for file handling. I am Looking for the setup examples and would get back to you.

Comment: Yes, I did not modify file location at all

Comment: I have read into dynamic permissions on the sdk site, it says that permissions are called dynamical while the app is in use and not just at installation. Ill post my permission setup in my manifest below the code I just posted.

Comment: can u send me that formatted somehow im going to add it to FileUtils.java before the class or just put it in answer cant get the sytex right im new with java

Comment: @AnthonyAccetturoIII added formatted code in my answer post.

Comment: I have been trying or hours and I am struggling, would it be possible for you to help me directly if I can give you something for your time?

Comment: accetturo@gmail.com

Ill be on for the next few hours

Answer (score 2):

You just need to read the stacktrace:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at nezibo.com.dreamception.utils.FileUtils.removeTMPFiles(FileUtils.java:31)
```

So check why your array might be `null` in FileUtils in line 31.

Comment: Posted code to FileUtil and line 31 in the orignal body, Thank u