# upgrade Nexus 7 to android 6, my app cannot access to sdcard anymore

Tags: android, sd-card, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have developed an app, installed on Nexus 7 android 5, which shows list of files in a directory on sd card. After upgrade to Android 6, it canot access to sd card anymore!

Here my code:

```
    File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    String ProjectPath = f.getPath();
    Log.w("path",ProjectPath);
    File list[]=f.listFiles();
    if(list.length>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            Log.w("path", list[i].getName());
    }
```

following permissions also added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.behy.myapplication, PID: 13472
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.behy.myapplication/com.behy.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.behy.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**EDIT 1**
After `File list[]=f.listFiles();`, `list` is `null`!

**EDIT 2**
I've corrected my code as follows and it works for Android.M as well as previous versions:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.w("path","ver: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                readFile();
            else
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2909);
        }
        else
            readFile();
    }
    @Override
    public  void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permission[], int[] grantesult){
        if(requestCode == 2909){
            if(grantesult.length>0 && grantesult[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                readFile();
        }
    }
    private void readFile(){
            File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            String ProjectPath = f.getPath();
            Log.w("path",ProjectPath);
            File list[]=f.listFiles();
            if(!f.exists() )return;
            for(File file:f.listFiles())
                Log.w("path", file.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: this error caused by nullpointerexception
check this ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495022/app-crashes-on-android-6-0-launch-logcat-included-new-developer?rq=1

Comment: correct, in android 6, `listFiles()` cusses nullpointerexception error but why in android 6. Moreover by applying modifications suggested in the link the problem is not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API 23 there is an option for Runtime permission.
you can check is permission granted with this code.

```
     if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    //place your code here
        }else{
//request for runtime permission
              }
```

for more about runtime permission read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: You are right, the reason is the new dynamic permission of android 6